# Image as function: Does someone know which Matlab or equivalent openCV function did they use to plot an image?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

**REVISED:**

**Topic: Image as function:**

Does someone know which Matlab or equivalent openCV function did they use to plot this image?

1) this is an actual image

[image]

2) for analysis plot an image on x,y plane

[image]

3) Smooth edges, guess what will it do original image?!!

[image]

4) original image after applying smoothing algo

[image]

I am taking Udacity, Intro to Computer Vision course. Their forums are old and very few people are taking this course. Response time is too slow. Please let me know if there is more info I can provide.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MATLAB [`surf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html) function makes plots like this:

```
img = imread('cameraman');
h = surf(img);
h.LineStyle = 'none';
colormap('gray')
view(160,75)
axis tight
axis equal
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try and find equivalent in matplotlib

Comment: Sorry, you were asking for MATLAB or OpenCV function... For matplotlib see here: https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#surface-plots

Comment: I am working with OpenCV - I thought if I can find Matlab function, It would be easy to find equivalent matplotlib function - but that is not the case at all.

Thanks for following up.

Answer (score 0):

The image look quite horrible. I can see a skull in the middle of the graph.

[image]

You could use matplotlib to draw 3d picture. There're several tutorial here : https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html

Hope that help

Comment: I've updated my question with what is happening. I'll check your link.